# C# Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, regex

this is my Set of string inside richtextbox1..

```
/Category/5
/Category/4
/Category/19
/Category/22
/Category/26
/Category/27
/Category/24
/Category/3
/Category/1
/Category/15
http://example.org/Category/15/noneedtoadd
```

i want to change all the starting "/" with some url like "http://example.com/"

output:

```
http://example.com/Category/5
http://example.com/Category/4
http://example.com/Category/19
http://example.com/Category/22
http://example.com/Category/26
http://example.com/Category/27
http://example.com/Category/24
http://example.com/Category/3
http://example.com/Category/1
http://example.com/Category/15
http://example.org/Category/15/noneedtoadd
```

just asking, what is the pattern for that? :)

Comment: Why use an impact wrench when you need a screwdriver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're dealing with URIs, you can take advantage of the [Uri Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) which can resolve relative URIs:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://example.com/");

Uri result1 = new Uri(baseUri, "/Category/5");
// result1 == {http://example.com/Category/5}

Uri result2 = new Uri(baseUri, "http://example.org/Category/15/noneedtoadd");
// result2 == {http://example.org/Category/15/noneedtoadd}
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a regular expression here. Iterate through the items in your list and use `String.Format` to build the desired URL.

```
String.Format(@"http://example.com{0}", str);
```

If you want to check to see whether one of the items in that textbox is a fully-formed URL before prepending the string, then use `String.StartsWith` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx)).

```
if (!String.StartsWith("http://")) { 
    // use String.Format 
}
```

Comment: what if inside the richtextbox, there's a string that does not start with **/** ?

Comment: So it's either /category/1 or category/1?

Answer (score 3):

The raw regex pattern is `^/` which means that it will match a slash at the beginning of the line.

```
Regex.Replace (text, @"^/", "http://example.com/")
```

Comment: how about if i added multiline "?m"

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "?m".  Do you mean RegexOptions.MultiLine?  If so, that doesn't matter for my regex.